# How to resolve memory bandwith problem with openmp fortrann77

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm tryng to parallelize a do loop which contains a lot of memory readings. The code is written in fortran 77.

I get no speedup at all. This is the parallelized code. It give correct results. In the code A,B,C,D are arrays defined in common sections like COMMON/ARR/ A(IM,JM,KM), ETC... and the loop is part of a subroutine which is called many times.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE) PRIVATE(AVGRVX,AVGRVR) 
!$OMP+ SHARED(A,B,AQX,AQR,SOURCEP,C,D,JMMM,IMMM)

 DO K=1,KMMM
 DO J=1,JMMM  
 DO I=1,IMMM
      AVGRVX = A(I,J,K)+A(I,J,K+1)+A(I+1,J,K)+A(I+1,J,K+1)
      AVGRVR = B(I,J,K)+B(I,J,K+1)+B(I+1,J,K)+B(I+1,J,K+1)
      C(I,J,K)   = 0.25*(AVGRVX*AQX(I,J,K) + AVGRVR*AQR(I,J,K))
      SOURCEP(I,J,K ) = 0.0
      D(I,J,K)   = C(I,J,K)
 END DO
 END DO
 END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

The actual speedup is 0.98 X. Parallel version runs slowly than the serial one. I think this is because every thread is not doing a lot of calculations but simply accessing all the time the memory. It is not because of the dimension of JMMM,KMMM etc..If they becomes larger then the code becomes even slower. I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the code. Can translate the code, for example in fortran90/95 and using allocatable instead of common arrays bring some advantages ? Thank you

EDIT: Here it is the code I use to test the loop, with gfortran please compile with gfortran -fopenmp -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-integer-8 -fdefault-double-8 -mcmodel=large -O3 thiscode.f :

```
  PARAMETER(KMM1=70, JM=2500 , IMM1=70  )
  COMMON/VEC/ AQX(IMM1,JM,KMM1),AQR(IMM1,JM,KMM1), 
 &           A(IMM1,JM,KMM1),B(IMM1,JM,KMM1),           
 &           C(IMM1,JM,KMM1),D(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
 &           SOURCE(IMM1,JM,KMM1)


  COMMON/PARVEC/ CP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),SOURCEP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
 &               DP(IMM1,JM,KMM1)
  COMMON/VRB/ KMMM,JMMM,IMMM
  include 'omp_lib.h'
  DOUBLE PRECISION SEC,SEC1


  KMMM=60
  JMMM=150
  IMMM=60

  CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(4)
  CALL RANDOM_SEED()

  DO K=1,KMM1
  DO J=1,JM
  DO I=1,IMM1

      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(A(I,J,K))
      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(B(I,J,K))
      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(AQX(I,J,K))
      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(AQR(I,J,K))
      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(SOURCE(I,J,K))



  END DO
  END DO
  END DO

  SEC1 = omp_get_wtime()
  CALL SERIAL
  SEC = omp_get_wtime() - SEC1
  WRITE(6,*) '#CPU SERIAL=', SEC, 'SECONDS.'

  SEC1 = omp_get_wtime()

  CALL PARAL


  SEC = omp_get_wtime() - SEC1
  WRITE(6,*) '#CPU PARALLEL=', SEC, 'SECONDS.'





  DO K=1,KMM1
  DO J=1,JM
  DO I=1,IMM1

  IF(CP(I,J,K).NE.C(I,J,K)) THEN
      WRITE(6,*) 'ERROR'
  END IF
  IF(DP(I,J,K).NE.D(I,J,K)) THEN
      WRITE(6,*) 'ERROR'
  END IF

  END DO
  END DO
  END DO



  STOP
  END






  SUBROUTINE SERIAL
  PARAMETER(KMM1=70, JM=2500 , IMM1=70  )
  COMMON/VEC/ AQX(IMM1,JM,KMM1),AQR(IMM1,JM,KMM1), 
 &           A(IMM1,JM,KMM1),B(IMM1,JM,KMM1),           
 &           C(IMM1,JM,KMM1),D(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
 &           SOURCE(IMM1,JM,KMM1)


  COMMON/PARVEC/ CP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),SOURCEP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
 &               DP(IMM1,JM,KMM1)
  COMMON/VRB/ KMMM,JMMM,IMMM



  DO K=1,KMMM
  DO J=1,JMMM  
  DO I=1,IMMM
      AVGRVX = A(I,J,K)+A(I,J,K+1)+A(I+1,J,K)+A(I+1,J,K+1)
      AVGRVR = B(I,J,K)+B(I,J,K+1)+B(I+1,J,K)+B(I+1,J,K+1)
      C(I,J,K)   = 0.25*(AVGRVX*AQX(I,J,K) + AVGRVR*AQR(I,J,K))
      SOURCE(I,J,K ) = 0.0
      D(I,J,K)   = C(I,J,K)
  END DO
  END DO
  END DO






  RETURN
  END


  SUBROUTINE PARAL



  PARAMETER(KMM1=70, JM=2500 , IMM1=70  )
  COMMON/VEC/ AQX(IMM1,JM,KMM1),AQR(IMM1,JM,KMM1), 
 &           A(IMM1,JM,KMM1),B(IMM1,JM,KMM1),           
 &           C(IMM1,JM,KMM1),D(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
 &           SOURCE(IMM1,JM,KMM1)


  COMMON/PARVEC/ CP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),SOURCEP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
 &               DP(IMM1,JM,KMM1)
  COMMON/VRB/ KMMM,JMMM,IMMM





!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE) PRIVATE(AVGRVX,AVGRVR) 
!$OMP+ SHARED(A,B,AQX,AQR,SOURCEP,CP,DP,JMMM,IMMM)
  DO K=1,KMMM
  DO J=1,JMMM  
  DO I=1,IMMM
      AVGRVX = A(I,J,K)+A(I,J,K+1)+A(I+1,J,K)+A(I+1,J,K+1)
      AVGRVR = B(I,J,K)+B(I,J,K+1)+B(I+1,J,K)+B(I+1,J,K+1)
      CP(I,J,K)   = 0.25*(AVGRVX*AQX(I,J,K) + AVGRVR*AQR(I,J,K))
      SOURCEP(I,J,K ) = 0.0
      DP(I,J,K)   = CP(I,J,K)
  END DO
  END DO
  END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO



  RETURN
  END
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Forrran questions. Use the version tags for version specific questions. There is no point listing all of them.

Comment: So this is a five pont Laplacian, right? There is a lot of literature about this. Did you try any loop tiling? Ehat kind of hardware do you have? How many threads?

Comment: You have 3 nested loops (i, j, k) but you don't use 'COLLAPSE' directive. Try adding this directive and check if you have race condition or not.

Comment: It would be great if you could post a short self-contained example that we could run and test. Peoole will be more likely willing to test a modification of your code if they don't have to write the whole initialization and time measurement again. Incidsntally, how are you measuring time? I hope not by using `cpu_time()`.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm testing with 4cores intel 5 8250, 8 GB ram. This is for future open source so it is important performance portability.

Comment: For a future opensource I would recommenda somewhat modern style in this century. Free source form, `use openmp`, no common blocks, parameter as attributes and so on.

Comment: For the original loops, you can move `SOURCEP(I,J,K ) = 0.0` outside of the loops and simply do `SOURCEP = 0`.  gfortran will use memset to zero the memory.  You can do likewise with `D(I,J,K) = C(I,J,K)` where outside the loops you use `D = C`.

Comment: @Steve I can move sourcep=0 and D=C outside the loop but the main problem with low parallel performance remains.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm parallelizing a big old program and to not use common blocks means rewrite it, not from scratch for sure, but it is a pain. What benefit can I obtain porting it for example to f90 ? Can this solve the loop problem ?

Comment: I think you'll need to consider @Vladimir's advice in looking into a tiling scheme if the sizes of the arrays are large.  If `IMMM` and `JMMM` are large, then `A(I,J,K)+A(I,J,K+1)` could be blowing out the cache.  PS: You can also move the multiplication by 0.25 out of the loops with `D = C / 4`.

Comment: @Steve moving these arrays out of the loop makes things worse. I've tried tiling the loops. If one knows the tiling factor, in the best case it gives no benefit (~1.05X speedup).